# How to attach Event Handler to JavaFX Stage/Window Minimize Button?

Tags: java, javafx

I need to hide the stage window when the window's minimize button is clicked. I'm doing everything is java code not in the scripting language. How can I attach a window event handler to a JavaFX stage window minimize button?

Comment: Is it a decorated Stage (e.g. the minimize button part of the OS generated window frame)?  What is your definition of "hide" and how is it different from the default behaviour which occurs when you currently click the window's minimize button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Attach a listener to your Stage's [iconified property](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#iconifiedProperty%28%29).

```
stage.iconifiedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
  @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> prop, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
    System.out.println("Iconified? " + newValue);
  }
});
```

Comment: What can I do if I want to consume the event?

Comment: It's not really an [event](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html), it's a property change, so you can't [consume](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html#consume--) it as there is no API for that.